# Object.__proto__ returns a function. What does that mean?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype-chain

In Chrome,

`Object.__proto__`        returns     ƒ () { [native code] }

whereas

`Function.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`    returns    null

Also, typeof Object is Function.

If type of Object is Function, Isn't everything in JavaScript a function?

I'm a newbie, Please help me out...

Comment: `Object` is a constructor, which is a function.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the context of your question. Where do the code snippets come from? Are they the result of a console.log?

Answer (score 0):

`__proto__` is a getter/setter on `Object.prototype` which can get the object's internal prototype (if gotten), or set it (if set).

For `Object.__proto__`, `Object` is a constructor function, and all functions have an internal prototype of `Function.prototype`, so that's what you're seeing:

```js
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype);
```

The prototype chain is:

```
null <- Object.prototype <- Function.prototype <- Object
```

In contrast, with:

```
Function.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
```

The prototype chain is:

```
null <- Object.prototype <- Function.prototype <- Function
```

So, access `__proto__` 3 times from `Function`, and you get to `null`.

> If type of Object is Function, Isn't everything in JavaScript a function?

`Object` is a function only because it's *possible* to call it as a constructor (which is a very weird thing to do in most cases, but it's technically permitted by the language).

```
const doNotDoThis = new Object();
```

`Object` is a constructor - this is very different from `Object.prototype`, which is a plain object. Most non-primitives inherit from `Object.prototype`, but only functions inherit from `Function.prototype`.